# What is the story of Madonna Oriente?

Tags: witchcraft, medieval-europe, italy

I stumbled upon the Wikipedia article on Madonna Oriente, a mysterious religious figure of 14th century Milan:

> Madonna Oriente or Signora Oriente (Lady of the East), also known as La Signora del Gioco (The Lady of the Game), are names of an alleged religious figure, as described by two Italian women who were executed by the Inquisition in 1390 as witches.
>
> The story which they are reported to have told is an elaborate and fantastical tale of occult religious rituals practised at the houses of wealthy individuals in Milan, Italy, where a woman known as the Madonna Oriente, possibly regarded as a goddess by her followers, performed magical acts such as the resurrection of slaughtered animals.
>
> The two women, Sibilla Zanni and Pierina de' Bugatis, were brought before the Inquisition first in 1384, and with their story apparently dismissed as fantasy, were sentenced only to minor penance. When they were investigated again in 1390, however, they were charged with consorting with the Devil, condemned, and executed.
>
> <sub>Source: Wikipedia contributors. (2017, July 8). Madonna Oriente. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 13:27, February 24, 2018, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Madonna_Oriente&oldid=789686368</sub>

Unfortunately, the article is very light on sources. Where can I find more details on the "fantastical tale of occult religious rituals" that cost the two women their lives? What do we know of the central figure of the story, Madonna Oriente? What was her connection with the east, and what is "the game" attested in her Italian name?